# What is base class in Scala like Object in Java?

Tags: scala

In Java, Object is the base class, which is extended by all other classes. What is the equivalent base class in Scala?

Answer (score 4):

Not so fast! ;)

The question seems somewhat ill-posed, because primitive types do not extend from `Object` in Java. Therefore, Java simply isn't like Scala. The base class of all *reference types* (what corresponds to classes that subclass `Object` in Java) is actually `AnyRef`, not `Any`.

Indeed, [Scala Tour page about unified types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html) states:

> AnyRef represents reference types. All non-value types are defined as reference types. Every user-defined type in Scala is a subtype of AnyRef. If Scala is used in the context of a Java runtime environment, AnyRef corresponds to java.lang.Object.

The base class of all types (`Any`) and the base class of all reference types (`AnyRef`) are two separate concepts.

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer. It is of type Any.

http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-eight-scalas-type-hierarchy-and-object-equality/